# Don't create partition schema in external devices

Tags: partition, flash-memory

Is right to create a filesystem without to create a partition table in external devices non-boot?

I've created directly a filesystem into a memory card (SD) and it has been mounted automatically when I inserted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most FOSS *nices do not have an issue with partition tables on USB keys, SD cards, etc. It is typically the closed OSes (with one in particular) that act strange with such a configuration.